# XAMPP - Object not found! on any files/directories

Tags: php, apache, xampp, localhost

Having a problem trying to install XAMPP on my Windows 7 machine. Essentially when I start apache and mysql the xampp index page (localhost) works fine. In my local file directory I have tried this:

In:
C:\xampp\htdocs
I've created a file called 'test.php' then in the Web Browser I have tried localhost/test.php
and I get the 'Object not found!' error.

I have tried creating a directory called:
C:\xampp\htdocs\oop
then added a index file:
C:\xampp\htdocs\oop\index.php

and in the Web Browser tried 'localhost/oop' and 'localhost/oop/index.php' but am receiving the same error.

My error log is:

```
[Sat Apr 19 22:09:09.742135 2014] [ssl:warn] [pid 3508:tid 260] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sat Apr 19 22:09:10.248164 2014] [ssl:warn] [pid 3508:tid 260] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sat Apr 19 22:09:10.346169 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3508:tid 260] AH00455: Apache/2.4.9 (Win32) OpenSSL/0.9.8y PHP/5.4.27 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Apr 19 22:09:10.346169 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3508:tid 260] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC10 Server built: Mar 17 2014 11:15:11
[Sat Apr 19 22:09:10.346169 2014] [core:notice] [pid 3508:tid 260] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Sat Apr 19 22:09:10.365170 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3508:tid 260] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 2692
[Sat Apr 19 22:09:11.325225 2014] [ssl:warn] [pid 2692:tid 272] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sat Apr 19 22:09:11.687246 2014] [ssl:warn] [pid 2692:tid 272] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sat Apr 19 22:09:11.734249 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2692:tid 272] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Sat Apr 19 22:14:57.151005 2014] [ssl:warn] [pid 5348:tid 260] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sat Apr 19 22:14:57.207008 2014] [core:warn] [pid 5348:tid 260] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Sat Apr 19 22:14:57.461023 2014] [ssl:warn] [pid 5348:tid 260] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sat Apr 19 22:14:57.514026 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5348:tid 260] AH00455: Apache/2.4.9 (Win32) OpenSSL/0.9.8y PHP/5.4.27 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Apr 19 22:14:57.514026 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5348:tid 260] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC10 Server built: Mar 17 2014 11:15:11
[Sat Apr 19 22:14:57.514026 2014] [core:notice] [pid 5348:tid 260] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Sat Apr 19 22:14:57.517026 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5348:tid 260] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 2356
[Sat Apr 19 22:14:58.340073 2014] [ssl:warn] [pid 2356:tid 272] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sat Apr 19 22:14:58.659092 2014] [ssl:warn] [pid 2356:tid 272] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sat Apr 19 22:14:58.717095 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2356:tid 272] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

Other things which I've tried:

In the httpd.conf file I have changed the 'Listen 80' to 'Listen 1337' (Skype is also turned off) but it doesn't resolve anything.

I have also looked at the Documentroot and it seems fine:

```
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs">
```

I've tried:

```
DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs"
<Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs">
```

But the same problem.

I'm new to using XAMPP and configuring it so any help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Have to tried to reinstall the xampp server? some user have been getting the same issue  [bitnami community link](https://community.bitnami.com/t/apache-error-server-certificate-does-not-include-an-id-which-matches-the-server-name/52679)

Answer (score 0):

Try to put that test.php file in a folder (eg.demo) inside htdocs and then try to browse

```
  http://localhost/demo/test.php
```

hope this would help you.

Answer (score 0):

Look into your /etc/httpd.conf file and check if you have Virtual hosts activated.

I you have it activated, check your etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf file. You might have set up a VirtualHost already.